# midi problem with badly formatted midi bytes

Tags: python, midi

when I try to run these code, I found there has a problem about

```
MidiException
badly formatted midi bytes, got: b'RIFF\xb8\xa7\x00\x00RMIDdata\x04\xa7\x00\x00'
  File "D:\music_gen_deep_learning-master\train_single.py", line 33, in get_notes
    midi = converter.parse(file)
  File "D:\music_gen_deep_learning-master\train_single.py", line 16, in train_network
    notes = get_notes()
  File "D:\music_gen_deep_learning-master\train_single.py", line 135, in <module>
    train_network()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from importlib.resources import path
from music21 import *
import glob
import pickle
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint


def train_network():
    notes = get_notes()

    # get amount of pitch names
    n_vocab = len(set(notes))

    network_input, network_output = prepare_sequences(notes, n_vocab)

    model = create_network(network_input, n_vocab)

    train(model, network_input, network_output)


def get_notes():
    notes = []  # contains elements only
    rest = True
    for file in glob.glob("midi/*.mid"):
        # file = "midi/Wtcii01a.mid"
        midi = converter.parse(file)
        print("Parsing %s" % file)
        notes_to_parse = None
        try:  # file has instrument parts
            inst = instrument.partitionByInstrument(midi)
            print("Number of instrument parts: " + str(len(inst.parts)))
            notes_to_parse = inst.parts[0].recurse()
        except:  # file has notes in a flat structure
            notes_to_parse = midi.flat.notes

        for element in notes_to_parse:
            if isinstance(element, note.Note):
                notes.append(str(element.pitch))
            elif isinstance(element, chord.Chord):
                notes.append('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.normalOrder))
            elif isinstance(element, note.Rest) and rest:
                notes.append("rest")

    with open('data/notes', 'wb') as filepath:
        pickle.dump(notes, filepath)

    # for note in notes:
    #     print(note)

    return notes


def prepare_sequences(notes, n_vocab):
    pitchnames = sorted(set(item for item in notes))
    note_to_int = dict((notes, number)
                       for number, notes in enumerate(pitchnames))
    print("Dictionary size: %f" % len(note_to_int))

    sequence_length = 100

    network_input = []
    network_output = []

    # create input sequences and the corresponding outputs
    print("Create input sequences and the corresponding outputs")
    for i in range(0, len(notes) - sequence_length, 1):
        sequence_in = notes[i:i + sequence_length]
        sequence_out = notes[i + sequence_length]
        network_input.append([note_to_int[char] for char in sequence_in])
        network_output.append(note_to_int[sequence_out])

        # print("outside of for loop", i)

    n_patterns = len(network_input)

    # reshape the input into a format compatible with LSTM layers
    print("Reshape the input into a format compatible with LSTM layers")
    network_input = numpy.reshape(
        network_input, (n_patterns, sequence_length, 1))
    # normalize input
    print("Normalize input")
    network_input = network_input / float(n_vocab)

    network_output = np_utils.to_categorical(network_output)
    return (network_input, network_output)


def create_network(network_input, n_vocab):
    # Creating model
    print("Creating model")
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(
        512,
        input_shape=(network_input.shape[1], network_input.shape[2]),
        return_sequences=True
    ))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(LSTM(512))
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(n_vocab))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

    return model


def train(model, network_input, network_output):
    # Training model
    print("Training model")
    filepath = "weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}-bigger.hdf5"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath,
        monitor='loss',
        verbose=0,
        save_best_only=True,
        mode='min'
    )
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

    model.fit(network_input, network_output, epochs=200,
              batch_size=64, callbacks=callbacks_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_network()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).